# using android mediaPlayer object for multiple dataSources, use of release();

Tags: android, methods, media-player

I have several raw sound files that I want to play using the MediaPlayer class in the android API, before I change the data source to a different file do I have to call release(); The documentation says that the release(); method will end the MediaPlayer object, I am using the same MediaPlayer object to switch between the different raw files so will that interfere, or do I just call release after the program ends

Answer (score 0):

Call `reset()` first. It resets the MediaPlayer to its uninitialized state. Then you will have to initialize it again by setting the data source and calling `prepare()`. Call `release()` once you are done with the MediaPlayer instance.