# Media player error(-38,0)

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

I am trying to play multiple audio files simultaneously. However, I do get this error(mentioned in title) . I would like to know what's the cause of it and how do I fix it. 
Note: Similar questions were refferred, but did not help me to fix it.

```
try {
        mp.setDataSource(text);
        mp.prepare();
        mp.setVolume(0.4f, 0.4f);




        songPlayer.setDataSource(song);
        songPlayer.prepare();
        songPlayer.setLooping(true);


        voicePlayer.setDataSource(voice);
        voicePlayer.prepare();
        voicePlayer.setLooping(true);
        voicePlayer.wait(5000);
        voicePlayer.setVolume(0.5f,0.5f);

    }
    catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IllegalMonitorStateException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    final Handler hlr = new Handler();

   final Runnable looper = new Runnable() {
       @Override
       public void run()
       {
           if(mp!=null)
           {

                mp.stop();

           }

           mp.start();

       }
   };





    mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp)
        {
            hlr.postDelayed(looper, 5000);
        }
    });

    mp.start();

    songPlayer.start();
    voicePlayer.start();
```

Here is the logcat as well:

```
> 09-14 21:48:17.293    8309-8309/zyia.alarm.zyia.zyia E/MediaPlayer﹕ start called in state 1
09-14 21:48:17.293    8309-8309/zyia.alarm.zyia.zyia E/MediaPlayer﹕ error (-38, 0)
09-14 21:48:17.304    8309-8309/zyia.alarm.zyia.zyia E/MediaPlayer﹕ Should have subtitle controller already set
09-14 21:48:17.305    8309-8309/zyia.alarm.zyia.zyia E/MediaPlayer﹕ Should have subtitle controller already set
09-14 21:48:17.305    8309-8309/zyia.alarm.zyia.zyia E/MediaPlayer﹕ Error (-38,0)
09-14 21:48:27.250    8309-8309/zyia.alarm.zyia.zyia E/MediaPlayer﹕ start called in state 64
09-14 21:48:27.250    8309-8309/zyia.alarm.zyia.zyia E/MediaPlayer﹕ error (-38, 0)
09-14 21:48:27.250    8309-8309/zyia.alarm.zyia.zyia E/MediaPlayer﹕ Error (-38,0)
09-14 21:48:32.255    8309-8309/zyia.alarm.zyia.zyia E/MediaPlayer﹕ stop called in state 0
09-14 21:48:32.255    8309-8309/zyia.alarm.zyia.zyia E/MediaPlayer﹕ error (-38, 0)
09-14 21:48:32.258    8309-8309/zyia.alarm.zyia.zyia E/MediaPlayer﹕ start called in state 0
09-14 21:48:32.258    8309-8309/zyia.alarm.zyia.zyia E/MediaPlayer﹕ error (-38, 0)
09-14 21:48:32.258    8309-8309/zyia.alarm.zyia.zyia E/MediaPlayer﹕ Error (-38,0)
09-14 21:48:32.258    8309-8309/zyia.alarm.zyia.zyia E/MediaPlayer﹕ Error (-38,0)
09-14 21:48:37.263    8309-8309/zyia.alarm.zyia.zyia E/MediaPlayer﹕ stop called in state 0
09-14 21:48:37.263    8309-8309/zyia.alarm.zyia.zyia E/MediaPlayer﹕ error (-38, 0)
09-14 21:48:37.271    8309-8309/zyia.alarm.zyia.zyia E/MediaPlayer﹕ start called in state 0
09-14 21:48:37.272    8309-8309/zyia.alarm.zyia.zyia E/MediaPlayer﹕ error (-38, 0)
09-14 21:48:37.272    8309-8309/zyia.alarm.zyia.zyia E/MediaPlayer﹕ stop called in state 0
09-14 21:48:37.272    8309-8309/zyia.alarm.zyia.zyia E/MediaPlayer﹕ error (-38, 0)
09-14 21:48:37.275    8309-8309/zyia.alarm.zyia.zyia E/MediaPlayer﹕ start called in state 0
09-14 21:48:37.275    8309-8309/zyia.alarm.zyia.zyia E/MediaPlayer﹕ error (-38, 0)
09-14 21:48:37.276    8309-8309/zyia.alarm.zyia.zyia E/MediaPlayer﹕ Error (-38,0)
09-14 21:48:37.276    8309-8309/zyia.alarm.zyia.zyia E/MediaPlayer﹕ Error (-38,0)
09-14 21:48:37.276    8309-8309/zyia.alarm.zyia.zyia E/MediaPlayer﹕ Error (-38,0)
09-14 21:48:37.276    8309-8309/zyia.alarm.zyia.zyia E/MediaPlayer﹕ Error (-38,0)
09-14 21:48:42.281    8309-8309/zyia.alarm.zyia.zyia E/MediaPlayer﹕ stop called in state 0
09-14 21:48:42.281    8309-8309/zyia.alarm.zyia.zyia E/MediaPlayer﹕ error (-38, 0)
09-14 21:48:42.287    8309-8309/zyia.alarm.zyia.zyia E/MediaPlayer﹕ start called in state 0
09-14 21:48:42.287    8309-8309/zyia.alarm.zyia.zyia E/MediaPlayer﹕ error (-38, 0)
09-14 21:48:42.287    8309-8309/zyia.alarm.zyia.zyia E/MediaPlayer﹕ stop called in state 0
09-14 21:48:42.287    8309-8309/zyia.alarm.zyia.zyia E/MediaPlayer﹕ error (-38, 0)
09-14 21:48:42.289    8309-8309/zyia.alarm.zyia.zyia E/MediaPlayer﹕ start called in state 0
09-14 21:48:42.289    8309-8309/zyia.alarm.zyia.zyia E/MediaPlayer﹕ error (-38, 0)
09-14 21:48:42.289    8309-8309/zyia.alarm.zyia.zyia E/MediaPlayer﹕ stop called in state 0
09-14 21:48:42.289    8309-8309/zyia.alarm.zyia.zyia E/MediaPlayer﹕ error (-38, 0)
09-14 21:48:42.296    8309-8309/zyia.alarm.zyia.zyia E/MediaPlayer﹕ start called in state 0
09-14 21:48:42.297    8309-8309/zyia.alarm.zyia.zyia E/MediaPlayer﹕ error (-38, 0)
09-14 21:48:42.297    8309-8309/zyia.alarm.zyia.zyia E/MediaPlayer﹕ stop called in state 0
09-14 21:48:42.297    8309-8309/zyia.alarm.zyia.zyia E/MediaPlayer﹕ error (-38, 0)
09-14 21:48:42.299    8309-8309/zyia.alarm.zyia.zyia E/MediaPlayer﹕ start called in state 0
09-14 21:48:42.299    8309-8309/zyia.alarm.zyia.zyia E/MediaPlayer﹕ error (-38, 0)
09-14 21:48:42.299    8309-8309/zyia.alarm.zyia.zyia E/MediaPlayer﹕ Error (-38,0)
09-14 21:48:42.299    8309-8309/zyia.alarm.zyia.zyia E/MediaPlayer﹕ Error (-38,0)
09-14 21:48:42.300    8309-8309/zyia.alarm.zyia.zyia E/MediaPlayer﹕ Error (-38,0)
09-14 21:48:42.300    8309-8309/zyia.alarm.zyia.zyia E/MediaPlayer﹕ Error (-38,0)
09-14 21:48:42.300    8309-8309/zyia.alarm.zyia.zyia E/MediaPlayer﹕ Error (-38,0)
09-14 21:48:42.300    8309-8309/zyia.alarm.zyia.zyia E/MediaPlayer﹕ Error (-38,0)
09-14 21:48:42.300    8309-8309/zyia.alarm.zyia.zyia E/MediaPlayer﹕ Error (-38,0)
09-14 21:48:42.301    8309-8309/zyia.alarm.zyia.zyia E/MediaPlayer﹕ Error (-38,0)
09-14 21:48:47.305    8309-8309/zyia.alarm.zyia.zyia E/MediaPlayer﹕ stop called in state 0
09-14 21:48:47.305    8309-8309/zyia.alarm.zyia.zyia E/MediaPlayer﹕ error (-38, 0)
09-14 21:48:47.314    8309-8309/zyia.alarm.zyia.zyia E/MediaPlayer﹕ start called in state 0
09-14 21:48:47.314    8309-8309/zyia.alarm.zyia.zyia E/MediaPlayer﹕ error (-38, 0)
09-14 21:48:47.314    8309-8309/zyia.alarm.zyia.zyia E/MediaPlayer﹕ stop called in state 0
09-14 21:48:47.314    8309-8309/zyia.alarm.zyia.zyia E/MediaPlayer﹕ error (-38, 0)
09-14 21:48:47.318    8309-8309/zyia.alarm.zyia.zyia E/MediaPlayer﹕ start called in state 0
09-14 21:48:47.318    8309-8309/zyia.alarm.zyia.zyia E/MediaPlayer﹕ error (-38, 0)
09-14 21:48:47.319    8309-8309/zyia.alarm.zyia.zyia E/MediaPlayer﹕ stop called in state 0
09-14 21:48:47.319    8309-8309/zyia.alarm.zyia.zyia E/MediaPlayer﹕ error (-38, 0)
09-14 21:48:47.320    8309-8309/zyia.alarm.zyia.zyia E/MediaPlayer﹕ start called in state 0
09-14 21:48:47.321    8309-8309/zyia.alarm.zyia.zyia E/MediaPlayer﹕ error (-38, 0)
09-14 21:48:47.321    8309-8309/zyia.alarm.zyia.zyia E/MediaPlayer﹕ stop called in state 0
09-14 21:48:47.321    8309-8309/zyia.alarm.zyia.zyia E/MediaPlayer﹕ error (-38, 0)
09-14 21:48:47.323    8309-8309/zyia.alarm.zyia.zyia E/MediaPlayer﹕ start called in state 0
09-14 21:48:47.323    8309-8309/zyia.alarm.zyia.zyia E/MediaPlayer﹕ error (-38, 0)
09-14 21:48:47.323    8309-8309/zyia.alarm.zyia.zyia E/MediaPlayer﹕ stop called in state 0
09-14 21:48:47.323    8309-8309/zyia.alarm.zyia.zyia E/MediaPlayer﹕ error (-38, 0)
09-14 21:48:47.328    8309-8309/zyia.alarm.zyia.zyia E/MediaPlayer﹕ start called in state 0
09-14 21:48:47.328    8309-8309/zyia.alarm.zyia.zyia E/MediaPlayer﹕ error (-38, 0)
09-14 21:48:47.329    8309-8309/zyia.alarm.zyia.zyia E/MediaPlayer﹕ stop called in state 0
09-14 21:48:47.329    8309-8309/zyia.alarm.zyia.zyia E/MediaPlayer﹕ error (-38, 0)
09-14 21:48:47.349    8309-8309/zyia.alarm.zyia.zyia E/MediaPlayer﹕ start called in state 0
09-14 21:48:47.350    8309-8309/zyia.alarm.zyia.zyia E/MediaPlayer﹕ error (-38, 0)
09-14 21:48:47.350    8309-8309/zyia.alarm.zyia.zyia E/MediaPlayer﹕ stop called in state 0
09-14 21:48:47.350    8309-8309/zyia.alarm.zyia.zyia E/MediaPlayer﹕ error (-38, 0)
09-14 21:48:47.359    8309-8309/zyia.alarm.zyia.zyia E/MediaPlayer﹕ start called in state 0
09-14 21:48:47.359    8309-8309/zyia.alarm.zyia.zyia E/MediaPlayer﹕ error (-38, 0)
09-14 21:48:47.362    8309-8309/zyia.alarm.zyia.zyia E/MediaPlayer﹕ stop called in state 0
09-14 21:48:47.362    8309-8309/zyia.alarm.zyia.zyia E/MediaPlayer﹕ error (-38, 0)
09-14 21:48:47.363    8309-8309/zyia.alarm.zyia.zyia E/MediaPlayer﹕ start called in state 0
09-14 21:48:47.364    8309-8309/zyia.alarm.zyia.zyia E/MediaPlayer﹕ error (-38, 0)
09-14 21:48:47.364    8309-8309/zyia.alarm.zyia.zyia E/MediaPlayer﹕ Error (-38,0)
09-14 21:48:47.364    8309-8309/zyia.alarm.zyia.zyia E/MediaPlayer﹕ Error (-38,0)
09-14 21:48:47.364    8309-8309/zyia.alarm.zyia.zyia E/MediaPlayer﹕ Error (-38,0)
09-14 21:48:47.365    8309-8309/zyia.alarm.zyia.zyia E/MediaPlayer﹕ Error (-38,0)
09-14 21:48:47.365    8309-8309/zyia.alarm.zyia.zyia E/MediaPlayer﹕ Error (-38,0)
09-14 21:48:47.368    8309-8309/zyia.alarm.zyia.zyia E/MediaPlayer﹕ Error (-38,0)
09-14 21:48:47.368    8309-8309/zyia.alarm.zyia.zyia E/MediaPlayer﹕ Error (-38,0)
09-14 21:48:47.369    8309-8309/zyia.alarm.zyia.zyia E/MediaPlayer﹕ Error (-38,0)
09-14 21:48:47.369    8309-8309/zyia.alarm.zyia.zyia E/MediaPlayer﹕ Error (-38,0)
09-14 21:48:47.369    8309-8309/zyia.alarm.zyia.zyia E/MediaPlayer﹕ Error (-38,0)
09-14 21:48:47.369    8309-8309/zyia.alarm.zyia.zyia E/MediaPlayer﹕ Error (-38,0)
09-14 21:48:47.369    8309-8309/zyia.alarm.zyia.zyia E/MediaPlayer﹕ Error (-38,0)
09-14 21:48:47.370    8309-8309/zyia.alarm.zyia.zyia E/MediaPlayer﹕ Error (-38,0)
09-14 21:48:47.370    8309-8309/zyia.alarm.zyia.zyia E/MediaPlayer﹕ Error (-38,0)
09-14 21:48:47.370    8309-8309/zyia.alarm.zyia.zyia E/MediaPlayer﹕ Error (-38,0)
09-14 21:48:47.370    8309-8309/zyia.alarm.zyia.zyia E/MediaPlayer﹕ Error (-38,0)
09-14 21:48:52.370    8309-8309/zyia.alarm.zyia.zyia E/MediaPlayer﹕ stop called in state 0
09-14 21:48:52.370    8309-8309/zyia.alarm.zyia.zyia E/MediaPlayer﹕ error (-38, 0)
09-14 21:48:52.379    8309-8309/zyia.alarm.zyia.zyia E/MediaPlayer﹕ start called in state 0
09-14 21:48:52.379    8309-8309/zyia.alarm.zyia.zyia E/MediaPlayer﹕ error (-38, 0)
09-14 21:48:52.380    8309-8309/zyia.alarm.zyia.zyia E/MediaPlayer﹕ stop called in state 0
09-14 21:48:52.380    8309-8309/zyia.alarm.zyia.zyia E/MediaPlayer﹕ error (-38, 0)
09-14 21:48:52.382    8309-8309/zyia.alarm.zyia.zyia E/MediaPlayer﹕ start called in state 0
09-14 21:48:52.382    8309-8309/zyia.alarm.zyia.zyia E/MediaPlayer﹕ error (-38, 0)
09-14 21:48:52.383    8309-8309/zyia.alarm.zyia.zyia E/MediaPlayer﹕ stop called in state 0
09-14 21:48:52.383    8309-8309/zyia.alarm.zyia.zyia E/MediaPlayer﹕ error (-38, 0)
09-14 21:48:52.384    8309-8309/zyia.alarm.zyia.zyia E/MediaPlayer﹕ start called in state 0
09-14 21:48:52.384    8309-8309/zyia.alarm.zyia.zyia E/MediaPlayer﹕ error (-38, 0)
09-14 21:48:52.385    8309-8309/zyia.alarm.zyia.zyia E/MediaPlayer﹕ stop called in state 0
09-14 21:48:52.385    8309-8309/zyia.alarm.zyia.zyia E/MediaPlayer﹕ error (-38, 0)
09-14 21:48:52.387    8309-8309/zyia.alarm.zyia.zyia E/MediaPlayer﹕ start called in state 0
09-14 21:48:52.387    8309-8309/zyia.alarm.zyia.zyia E/MediaPlayer﹕ error (-38, 0)
09-14 21:48:52.387    8309-8309/zyia.alarm.zyia.zyia E/MediaPlayer﹕ stop called in state 0
09-14 21:48:52.387    8309-8309/zyia.alarm.zyia.zyia E/MediaPlayer﹕ error (-38, 0)
09-14 21:48:52.389    8309-8309/zyia.alarm.zyia.zyia E/MediaPlayer﹕ start called in state 0
09-14 21:48:52.389    8309-8309/zyia.alarm.zyia.zyia E/MediaPlayer﹕ error (-38, 0)
09-14 21:48:52.389    8309-8309/zyia.alarm.zyia.zyia E/MediaPlayer﹕ stop called in state 0
09-14 21:48:52.389    8309-8309/zyia.alarm.zyia.zyia E/MediaPlayer﹕ error (-38, 0)
09-14 21:48:52.410    8309-8309/zyia.alarm.zyia.zyia E/MediaPlayer﹕ start called in state 0
09-14 21:48:52.410    8309-8309/zyia.alarm.zyia.zyia E/MediaPlayer﹕ error (-38, 0)
09-14 21:48:52.420    8309-8309/zyia.alarm.zyia.zyia E/MediaPlayer﹕ stop called in state 0
09-14 21:48:52.423    8309-8309/zyia.alarm.zyia.zyia E/MediaPlayer﹕ error (-38, 0)
09-14 21:48:52.427    8309-8309/zyia.alarm.zyia.zyia E/MediaPlayer﹕ start called in state 0
09-14 21:48:52.428    8309-8309/zyia.alarm.zyia.zyia E/MediaPlayer﹕ error (-38, 0)
09-14 21:48:52.428    8309-8309/zyia.alarm.zyia.zyia E/MediaPlayer﹕ stop called in state 0
09-14 21:48:52.428    8309-8309/zyia.alarm.zyia.zyia E/MediaPlayer﹕ error (-38, 0)
09-14 21:48:52.439    8309-8309/zyia.alarm.zyia.zyia E/MediaPlayer﹕ start called in state 0
09-14 21:48:52.439    8309-8309/zyia.alarm.zyia.zyia E/MediaPlayer﹕ error (-38, 0)
09-14 21:48:52.442    8309-8309/zyia.alarm.zyia.zyia E/MediaPlayer﹕ stop called in state 0
09-14 21:48:52.443    8309-8309/zyia.alarm.zyia.zyia E/MediaPlayer﹕ error (-38, 0)
09-14 21:48:52.450    8309-8309/zyia.alarm.zyia.zyia E/MediaPlayer﹕ start called in state 0
09-14 21:48:52.450    8309-8309/zyia.alarm.zyia.zyia E/MediaPlayer﹕ error (-38, 0)
09-14 21:48:52.450    8309-8309/zyia.alarm.zyia.zyia E/MediaPlayer﹕ stop called in state 0
09-14 21:48:52.450    8309-8309/zyia.alarm.zyia.zyia E/MediaPlayer﹕ error (-38, 0)
09-14 21:48:52.451    8309-8309/zyia.alarm.zyia.zyia E/MediaPlayer﹕ start called in state 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I have played a bit with the MediaPlayer and maybe a reset of the player can help.

Also take a look here:
[using android mediaPlayer object for multiple dataSources, use of release();](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20536036/using-android-mediaplayer-object-for-multiple-datasources-use-of-release) 
Hope it helps.